# Dll of a single C# code behind page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I a using ASP.net website - 3.5 C#

I have a modification in a .cs page, I have to deliver only updates for this code behind file only to client. Is there any way to create dll for this page in the website ?

Comment: You can migrate from WebSite project to the Web Application

Comment: If the *.cs class is part of library, then why can't you ship the complete library itself. Is there any specific reason, why you want to compile a single class file into a dll?

Comment: check this [Releasing Single / Multiple Files To Pre Compiled ASP.net Web Site](http://www.jebarson.info/post/2011/05/04/Releasing-Single-Multiple-Files-To-Pre-Compiled-ASP-net-Web-Site.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the highlighted part as mentioned in the screen shot and Publish it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible to create an assembly from a single code behind page that is part of a website project.

The web project gets compiled into a single assembly - all code behind files become part of this assembly. An update to a single code behind file means that you need to recompile the project and deploy the updated assembly.

If you can change the project from a website project to a web application, this would be a different matter, as IIS would compile all code behind files on the fly, so updating a single code behind file is possible.

Answer (score 0):

To create an assembly you will need to create a project class library project. In this project you will create your .cs class file. When you build this it will produce the DLL file.

Unfortuantely you cannot create web pages in this type of project.
Now to use this in your website you can either add a project reference to this class library project, or add a file reference to the DLL it produced